# How do I use openvpn command line to use environment variables to connect?

Tags: openvpn, nordvpn

I have installed OpenVPN on my linux laptop.  I think it is OpenVPN version 2.

```
$ sudo openvpn --version

OpenVPN 2.4.4 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 19 2021
library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1c  28 May 2019, LZO 2.08
Originally developed by James Yonan
Copyright (C) 2002-2017 OpenVPN Technologies, Inc. <sales@openvpn.net>
Compile time defines: enable_async_push=no enable_comp_stub=no enable_crypto=yes enable_crypto_ofb_cfb=yes enable_debug=yes enable_def_auth=yes enable_dependency_tracking=no enable_dlopen=unknown enable_dlopen_self=unknown enable_dlopen_self_static=unknown enable_fast_install=needless enable_fragment=yes enable_iproute2=yes enable_libtool_lock=yes enable_lz4=yes enable_lzo=yes enable_maintainer_mode=no enable_management=yes enable_multihome=yes enable_pam_dlopen=no enable_pedantic=no enable_pf=yes enable_pkcs11=yes enable_plugin_auth_pam=yes enable_plugin_down_root=yes enable_plugins=yes enable_port_share=yes enable_selinux=no enable_server=yes enable_shared=yes enable_shared_with_static_runtimes=no enable_silent_rules=no enable_small=no enable_static=yes enable_strict=no enable_strict_options=no enable_systemd=yes enable_werror=no enable_win32_dll=yes enable_x509_alt_username=yes with_aix_soname=aix with_crypto_library=openssl with_gnu_ld=yes with_mem_check=no with_sysroot=no
```

It is connecting using NordVPN.  I can get it to connect by issuing something like

```
sudo openvpn /etc/openvpn/ovpn_tcp/us2950.nordvpn.com.tcp.ovpn
```

which works fine but it prompts for login and password.  I would rather set the login and password in environment variables.  I am totally lost after trying to google a solution and am drowning in complexities.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why not set the login and password in the ovpn config file by adding the username and password directive into the conf file, or using the auth-user-pass directive with a file with appropriate credentials.

Comment: Yes I ended up doing that using something like "auth-user-pass auth.txt" in the config file but it means that I have to run openvpn from the same folder that auth.txt is in and I was hoping for something more bullet proof.

Comment: For auth-user-pass did you try using the form auth-user-path /path/to/auth.txt ?

Comment: Hadn't tried that.  Didn't know that was an allowable syntax.

Comment: Per https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Openvpn24ManPage? (--config option) you can specify full paths.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`--auth-user-pass`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/openvpn) flag in combination with [bash process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

Suppose you have the environment variables `vpn_user` and `vpn_pw` holding your username and password.

The tricky part is that you have to wrap the full command in sudo to stop sudo from closing the file descriptors after the privilege escalation.

```bash
sudo bash -c 'openvpn /etc/openvpn/ovpn_tcp/us2950.nordvpn.com.tcp.ovpn --auth-user-pass <(echo -e "'${vpn_user}'\n'${vpn_pw}'")'
```

Note the `'` around the environment variables. They take them out of the string, to allow for substitution.